# changing hourly to daily data while there are some missing values in my hourly data

Tags: excel

how can I change my hourly to daily data while there are some missing values in my hourly data? my excel is like:

date        hour    ENERGY(MJ)
1/01/2002   0:00    0
1/01/2002   1:00    0
1/01/2002   2:00    0
1/01/2002   3:00    0
1/01/2002   4:00    0
1/01/2002   5:00    0
1/01/2002   6:00    0.15
1/01/2002   7:00    0.74
1/01/2002   8:00    1.46
1/01/2002   9:00    2.23
1/01/2002   10:00   2.89

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in A1:C12 you have 5 hourly readings (total 7.47MJ) which may be summed with `SUM(C2:C12)`, the divided with `5` derivable with `COUNTIF(C2:C12,">"&0)` to compute an average hourly rate from the data available, then scaled up for a full day by multiplying by `24`:

```
 =SUM(C2:C12)*24/COUNTIF(C2:C12,">"&0)
```